# Pandas: SettingWithCopyWarning:

Tags: python, pandas

I tried the following code to convert a column to "date":

```
df.['DATE'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
```

or

```
df.DATE =  pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
```

but I get the following error:

> /Users/xyz/anaconda3/envs/sensor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:517:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   self.obj[item] = s

I changed the code to the following:

```
df.loc[:,'DATE'] =  pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,'DATE'])
```

but I still get the same error.

same with this

```
for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i,'DATE'] =  pd.to_datetime(df.loc[i,'DATE'])
```

Comment: What is code before?

Comment: `df = data.loc[data.ID == 79]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need add [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df = data.loc[data.ID == 79]
```

to:

```
df = data.loc[data.ID == 79].copy()
```

If you modify values in `df` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`data`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: how to tell if the df is a `view` or a `copy`?

Comment: I think you can check it by `print (df.is_copy)`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the code you have not shown us.  Somewhere, you have done something like this:

```
df = other.loc[something]
```

That is the root cause of this error message.  You need to assign using `.loc` or similar directly into the original DataFrame:

```
other.loc[something, 'DATE'] = whatever
```