# What is the equivalent of a SQL count in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In sql, select a.*,count(a.id) as N from table a group by a.name would give me a new column 'N'containing the count as per my group by specification.

However in pandas, if I try df['name'].value_counts(), I get the count but not as a column in the original dataframe.

Is there a way to get the count as a column in the original dataframe in a single step/statement?

Comment: Not many of us know SQL enough to figure out what that query does so it would be helpful if you include a sample dataset with the desired output. From your description, `df.groupby('name').transform('count')` might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) function [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'name':list('aaabcc')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E name
0  a  4  7  1  5    a
1  b  5  8  3  3    a
2  c  4  9  5  6    a
3  d  5  4  7  9    b
4  e  5  2  1  2    c
5  f  4  3  0  4    c

df['new'] = df.groupby('name')['name'].transform('size')
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E name  new
0  a  4  7  1  5    a    3
1  b  5  8  3  3    a    3
2  c  4  9  5  6    a    3
3  d  5  4  7  9    b    1
4  e  5  2  1  2    c    2
5  f  4  3  0  4    c    2
```

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Comment: Hi Jezrael, I need the output as you have shown in your example. However when I try to do the same I get the following warning/error:      SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: I think there is problem in one row above and need `copy()` - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45170475/2901002)

Comment: Here is what I am doing dat1=pd.read_csv("C:\\Test.csv")
dat2=dat1[['Stock', 'Date', 'AdjClose', 'Volume']]
dat2['count'] = dat2.groupby('Stock')['Stock'].transform('count')

Comment: So need `dat2=dat1[['Stock', 'Date', 'AdjClose', 'Volume']].copy()`

Comment: If you modify values in `dat2` after you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`dat1`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: It create `deep` copy of object for new df, because in pandas indexing a DataFrame returns a reference to the initial DataFrame.