# SettingWithCopyWarning although I use .loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using the following code:

```
video_df_x.loc[:, 'duration'] = pd.to_datetime(video_df['datetime_2']) - pd.to_datetime(video_df_x['datetime_1'])
```

The code runs but gives me the following warning:

> C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:337:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead

I do not understand why I receive this error, since I am already using `.loc` in my code, which is recommended in the warning message.

Any insights?

Comment: that is just a warning as you are trying to create a column. what happens when you add `.copy()` at the end of each dataframe? `pd.to_datetime(video_df['datetime_2'].copy()) - pd.to_datetime(video_df_x['datetime_1'].copy())`

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas My guess is that `video_df_x` is slice of a dataframe, though without the full code I don't know for sure

Comment: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/ See 'Hidden chaining'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: SettingWithCopyWarning:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170312/pandas-settingwithcopywarning)