# How to ignore SettingWithCopyWarning using warnings.simplefilter()?

Tags: python, pandas, warnings, suppress-warnings

**The question:**

Can I ignore or prevent the `SettingWithCopyWarning` to be printed to the console using `warnings.simplefilter()`?

**The details:**

I'm running a few data cleaning routines using pandas, and those are executed in the simplest of ways using a [batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571244/creating-a-bat-file-for-python-script). One of the lines in my Python script triggers the `SettingWithCopyWarning` and is printed to the console. But it's also being echoed in the command prompt:

[image]

Aside from sorting out the [source of the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170312/pandas-settingwithcopywarning), is there any way I can prevent the error message from being printed to the prompt like I can with FutureWarnings like `warnings.simplefilter(action = "ignore", category = FutureWarning)`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Though I would strongly advise to fix the issue, it is possible to suppress the warning by importing it from `pandas.core.common`. I found where it's located on [GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8edf972fa07aa3b761756aba87c08fea98499687/pandas/core/common.py#L30).

Example:

```
import warnings

import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.common import SettingWithCopyWarning

warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore", category=SettingWithCopyWarning)

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, 3], B=[2, 3, 4]))
df[df['A'] > 2]['B'] = 5  # No warnings for the chained assignment!
```

Comment: Is this up to date? Trying to import SettingWithCopyWarning from pandas.core.common results in:
Cannot find reference 'SettingWithCopyWarning' in 'common.py'

Comment: I was able to find the warning here:
from pandas.errors import SettingWithCopyWarning

Answer (score 21):

You can use:

```
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)
# This code will not complain!
pd.reset_option("mode.chained_assignment")
```

Or if you prefer to use it inside a context:

```
with pd.option_context('mode.chained_assignment', None):
    # This code will not complain!
```

Answer (score 6):

The updated solution to suppress the SettingWithCopyWarning is:

```
import warnings
import pandas as pd
from pandas.errors import SettingWithCopyWarning
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=(SettingWithCopyWarning))
```